# Postdoc disenchantment

Tags: postdocs, job-search, research-topic

Recently, I attained my PhD in biophysics, with three publications in respectable journals, including one letter, and delivered seven conference talks, two of which were by invitation. While I wouldn't claim extraordinary prowess during my PhD, I certainly wasn't unsuccessful. I found a postdoc position in the US, and the role promised to bolster my academic pedigree. It's worth noting that I opted for a minor topic shift, which I believed could expand my skill set, although potentially slowing down my paper output as I had to learn a new topic. Perhaps I was too bold (and mistaken in this assumption)?

Having relocated from France to the United States, I've found the environment here to be remarkably welcoming. However, regrettably, the topic of my current research fails to captivate my interest. It's very complicated and the literature is daunting to say the least. But more severely, it's as though I've suddenly lost all passion for science. My PI communicated to me that I need to time and "meticulously review the literature" which seems impossible to me at the moment! It's not merely the complexity of the literature (although it certainly is intricate) but rather the pedagogical quality is severely lacking. There is no proper book about the theory of my topic; instead, I am confronted with method sections scattered across various research papers. Deciphering these sections from scratch proves exceedingly challenging.

Compounding matters, I find myself missing France and my long-term partner, despite the amicable social ambiance I've encountered here. Consequently, I've begun exploring (industry) opportunities back in France.

Thus, my questions is whether anyone else has experienced a similar sense of disenchantment and a loss of interest in something they once believed to be the cornerstone of their existence. What's more troubling is my increasing inability to cope with the feeling of inadequacy and incompetence, which has put me into a paralysing state of procrastination. If I persist in this self-defeating behaviour and self-doubt, termination of my contract seems inevitable, although somewhat intriguing, as it would trigger change ;-) Nonetheless, it's only been a month since I arrived, so perhaps my reaction is premature?

Comment: "I've begun exploring (industry) opportunities back in France." Why not academic opportunities?

Comment: What is your field, exactly?

Comment: Because my field is fairly small, I rather confine myself to "biophysics" without specifying the exact niche. I did not explore academic opportunities since don't think of my academic skills to highly. Perhaps being a female scientist exacerbates this sense of not belonging If I were to conclude my postdoc here, I would point toward my own incompetence and loss of interest for the role rather than the position or the supervision lacking certain aspects.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, probably not what you want to hear.

You need to decide if you are a technician with a PhD or a scientist. Because right now you hit a very common issue in cutting edge research.... the fact that it is cutting edge and not everything is spelled out neatly! This is where researchers want to be. It's messy, but you get to contribute to a growing area.

It sounds like you would rather things be spelled out and you have a neat path to just follow. The stress is probably compounded by being homesick, understandably.

So, decide. Are you a researcher who sees this as an opportunity, or are you a technician who is frustrated by lack of clear SOPs to follow?

Comment: I think right now, I need a neat path to just follow. I had a rather tight supervision during my PhD, maybe that compounds the problem. Genuinely, I want to be my own researcher and not be a sheep to follow instructions. If only I could find my curiosity again!

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth considering if you might need help with your mental health. Sometimes, the reason for losing interest isn't the topic, or the profession itself, but depression. Losing interest in things you used to like is the main symptom of depression, after all.

Please note, I'm not trying to diagnose depression over the internet. It's just something I, and many of my colleagues, have come across personally. So, I think it might be useful to consider this possibility as well.

And yes, I would say it makes sense to wait a bit. I've moved countries a lot, and the first month was never easy for me.

Comment: This is a valid point. Initially, I thought my lack of interest might be a sign of depression. However, given my diagnosed mental health condition from years ago, I'm quite familiar with the symptoms and don't believe I currently meet the criteria for clinical depression. Still, it's hard to judge objectively. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.